# How do I turn audio into video (that is, show the waveforms in a video)?

Tags: video, audio, software-recommendation

I have to create a video. Part of it involves "showing" a radio interview. Rather than just having a black screen and listening to the audio, I'd like to have a varying waveform on the screen and a caption.

Is there any free or cheap tool I can use that will do this?

---

*If I ask a friend to do it, is there anything in the Adobe Creative Suite that can do the job?*

Comment: Audacity should show you the sound wave; you could record - visually - the wave.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the "visualizer" tool you're probably looking for is an [oscilloscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscilloscope), which may inform your search.

Comment: You can use `ffmpeg` to convert directly - [ffmpeg convert audio into video](https://echowave.io/podcast-to-video/) Using [filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) you can get an aesthetically pleasing video.

Answer (score 66):

You can use `ffmpeg` to create video from audio using several filters.

---

## [ahistogram](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ahistogram)

Convert input audio to a video output, displaying the volume histogram.

[image: ahistogram]

**`ffmpeg`**

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -filter_complex \
"[0:a]ahistogram,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

**`ffplay`**

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.flac, asplit [a][out1]; [a] ahistogram [out0]"
```

See the [`ahistogram`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ahistogram) documentation for more options and examples.

---

## [aphasemeter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aphasemeter)

Convert input audio to a video output, displaying the audio phase.

[image: aphasemeter]

**`ffmpeg`**

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -filter_complex \
"[0:a]aphasemeter=s=1280x720:mpc=cyan,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

**`ffplay`**

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.wav, asplit [a][out1]; [a] aphasemeter=s=1280x720:mpc=cyan [out0]"
```

See the [`aphasemeter`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aphasemeter) documentation for more options and examples.

---

## [avectorscope](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#avectorscope)

[image: avectorscope filter]

Convert input audio to a video output, representing the audio vector scope.

**`ffmpeg`**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]avectorscope=s=1280x720,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

**`ffplay`**

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.mp3, asplit [a][out1]; \
[a] avectorscope=zoom=1.3:rc=2:gc=200:bc=10:rf=1:gf=8:bf=7 [out0]"
```

See the [`avectorscope`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#avectorscope) documentation for more options and examples.

---

## [showcqt](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showcqt)

[image: showcqt filter]

Convert input audio to a video output representing frequency spectrum with musical tone scale.

**`ffmpeg`**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showcqt,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

**`ffplay`**

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.mp4, asplit [a][out1]; [a] showcqt [out0]"
```

See the [`showcqt`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showcqt) documentation for more options and examples.

---

## [showfreqs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showfreqs)

Convert input audio to video output representing the audio power spectrum. Audio amplitude is on Y-axis while frequency is on X-axis.

[image: showfreqs]

**`ffmpeg`**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showfreqs=mode=line:fscale=log,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

**`ffplay`**

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.mp4, asplit [a][out1]; [a]  showfreqs=mode=line:fscale=log [out0]"
```

See the [`showfreqs`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showfreqs) documentation for more options and examples.

---

## [showspectrum](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showspectrum)

[image: showspectrum image]

Convert input audio to a video output, representing the audio frequency spectrum.

**`ffmpeg`**

```
ffmpeg -i input.oga -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showspectrum=s=1280x720,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

**`ffplay`**

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.oga, asplit [a][out1]; \
[a] showspectrum=mode=separate:color=intensity:slide=1:scale=cbrt [out0]"
```

See the [`showspectrum`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showspectrum) documentation for more options and examples.

---

## [showwaves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves)

[image: showwaves filter]

Convert input audio to a video output, representing the samples waves.

**`ffmpeg`**

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4a -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

**`ffplay`**

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.m4a, asplit [a][out1]; [a] showwaves [out0]"
```

See the [`showwaves`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves) documentation for more options and examples.

---

## [showvolume](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showvolume)

[image: showvolume filter]

Convert input audio volume to a video output.

**`ffmpeg`**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mka -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showvolume=f=1:b=4:w=720:h=68,format=yuv420p[vid]" \
-map "[vid]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

**`ffplay`**

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.mka, asplit [a][out1]; [a] showvolume=f=255:b=4:w=720:h=68 [out0]"
```

See the [`showvolume`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showvolume) documentation for more options and examples.

---

### Notes

- See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more detailed information regarding output quality.
- `format=yuv420p` makes sure that libx264 uses a pixel format that is compatible with crappy players like QuickTime.
- Instead of re-encoding by default, you can use `-c:a copy` to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio if your output container format supports the audio format. Think of stream copying (re-muxing) like a copy and paste – no re-encoding.

---

### Get `ffmpeg`

You should always use a recent version since development is very active. Links to builds of `ffmpeg` for Windows, OS X, and Linux are available on the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page. Or you can follow a step-by-step [guide to compile `ffmpeg`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

Comment: The OP will probably want to look at the other answers which link to After Effects tutorials, but these excellent ffmpeg examples are really useful to have here. Thanks!

Comment: @LordNeckbeard OP here. It's been a while, but I'm back, and this is a great answer.

Comment: I've just created a question http://superuser.com/questions/1184922/how-do-i-insert-a-background-image-on-spectrum-audio-effect-using-ffmpeg How can I set a background image?

Comment: For Ubuntu installation simply use `sudo apt install ffmpeg`. It includes `ffplay` and `ffprobe` which is all I needed for now. Your visualization techniques look promising for when playing song. When song paused the album artwork will be displayed instead.

Answer (score 6):

Adobe After Effects has a visualizer, [see](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YglOeu3-DYE)

There are also plugins such as [here](http://softwaresolution.informer.com/d/Photoshop_Visualizer_Plugin) for Photoshop.

Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 4):

I understood your question quite well. If you are trying to make a waveform pattern that moves according to the pitch and bass of your audio, then you can try this link.

http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorial/audio_to_animation/

Adobe After effects lets you do it easily. You can play along with the particle effects to get a more solid looking waveform.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Many music players have visualisers. Play the audio in one of them and use a screen-grabber to record the video.

You could also try to use gstreamer as described at http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=23

Another option is Sonic Candle, http://sourceforge.net/projects/soniccandle/

Answer (score 3):

After reading the great answer from LordNeckbeard I went on created a small script to make a visualization with ffmpeg and the showspectrum filter.
I also added an upload option for myself to encode directly to my remote server that has a better connection than at home to upload big videos. It also uses the great script [youtube-upload](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload)!

**EDIT:** uploading directly slows down the encoding process significantly!!

## Script

```
#!/bin/bash
# ffmpeg spectrum maker

action=$1

infile=$2

outfile=$3
upload_server="sftp://cloud"

upload_location="/home/master/videos/"

remote_command="youtube-upload --title=\"Remote_upload\" --privacy=\"private\" $upload_location$outfile"

#simple spectrum
filter1="showspectrum=s=1920x1080:slide=scroll:mode=combined:color=intensity:scale=cbrt:saturation=1:win_func=hann[tmp]"

#vertical mirror
filter2="[tmp]crop=iw:ih/2:0:ih/2-3,split[up][tmp];[tmp]vflip[down];[up][down]vstack[tmp]"

#horizontal mirror
filter3="[tmp]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:,split[left][tmp];[tmp]hflip[right];[left][right]hstack[tmp]"

#fisheye effect VERY SLOW!!! if used make change the size of the spectrum to (1920*11/10)x(1080*11/10) and use the crop filter below
filter4="[tmp]frei0r=filter_name=defish0r:filter_params=1.5|n[tmp]"

#make sure the resolution has the desired size
filter5="[tmp]crop=1920:1080"

#pass the stream to the output for ffplay
testpass="[tmp]copy[out0]"


vcodec="-codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune grain -crf 21 -preset medium -bf 2 -flags +cgop -r 25"

acodec="-codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart"

#acodec="-codec:a copy"

extraflags="-movflags +faststart "


if [ "$action" = "test" ]
then
        ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=$infile,asplit[a][out1];[a]$filter1;$filter2;$filter3;$testpass"
fi

if [ "$action" = "make" ]
then
        ffmpeg -i "$infile" -filter_complex "[0:a]$filter1;$filter2;$filter3" -map [tmp] -map 0:a $vcodec $acodec $extraflags "$outfile"
fi
if [ "$action" = "upload" ]
then
        ffmpeg -i "$infile" -filter_complex "[0:a]$filter1;$filter2;$filter3" -map [tmp] -map 0:a $vcodec $acodec $extraflags "$upload_server$upload_location$outfile"
        ssh cloud $remote_command
fi
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to After Effects, there's a plugin called [Trapcode Keys](http://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-sound-keys/) that can do this very effectively.  The results look really nice - I've used it on many projects for exactly what you've described, but it's not cheap - $150 on it's own, or $899 for the full Trapcode Suite.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for free using VEED.IO, this video explains how to do it (Disclaimer, I am the developer of VEED.IO)

Comment: You need to disclaim your ownership of this program, since it's illegal promotion otherwise.

Comment: Thank you @FlorianClaaßen, I have now added it.